# How to add interop reference for programmi Office Excel / Word

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

after navigating along looking for a solution to this problem i can't find yet a working solution. I want to do programming on excel with Visual Studio, i have Office 2010 installed on my machine with all features checked when the installation run. I create a project in Visual studio and i add a reference to Office 14 object Library

[image]

[image]

Then i try to define in my class using Interop libraries but...

[image]

...i can't find Interop!!! Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Microsoft Excel and Word interfaces are located in the

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

Namespaces respectively.
Add those references instead and it should work.

Comment: i can't add those references, they are not showed in intellisense nor in the dialog for adding references

Comment: They won't appear in Intellisense until you add them as a reference to your project in the Solutions Explorer.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx) explains how to add the references.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx) explains how to install the Interop if you do not have the Interop assemblies installed.